# How to write a table line by line with for loop

Tags: python, arrays, export-to-csv

I have different files in where I pick up some data/values in order to produce a table grouping everything.

Here is a small example of the code I am using:

```
stations = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCCC", "DDDD"]
datadir = "/home/data/"
table = []
for station in stations:
    os.chdir(datadir)
    nc = Dataset(station + ".nc", 'r+')
    p = (nc.variables['Rainf'][:,0,0]
    evap = nc.variables['Qle'][:,0,0]
    table.append(p)
    table.append(evap)
    table_t=list(table)
    with open (datadir + "table.csv", 'w') as ofile:
        writer = csv.writer(ofile)
        writer.writerow(table_t)
```

But this code only write all the results of all stations in one row. What do I need to change in order that for each station the code write the data/values on the next row?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `writer.writerows(table_t)` instead.

`writerows()` method takes the iteration and creates lines per item in the list.

Example:

```
data = [list(i) for i in 'abcde fhghi jklmn opqrs'.split()]

# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
#  ['f', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'i'], 
#  ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'], 
#  ['o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's']]

with open('test.csv','w') as file:
         writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
         writer.writerows(data)

# test.csv
# a,b,c,d,e
# f,h,g,h,i
# j,k,l,m,n
# o,p,q,r,s
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to iterate over the table you want to write out:

```
with open (datadir + "table.csv", 'w') as ofile:
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)
    for row in table:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

hope that helps.